# Solvented or Solvent-Free Grab Adhesives?

Tags: adhesive

Most makes of grab adhesive have both a Solvented or Solvent-Free version?

When and why should I used each of them……

Comment: Is a "grab adhesive" the same thing as a contact adhesive?

Comment: @keshlam, no it is like "no more nails"

Comment: OK. Hadn't heard the term before.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on just 2 things. What you're doing & what the labeling says. I use Loctite Power Grab for most of my situations & I haven't had a single issue yet, but I've only just gotten to 10-years on stuff where I first used it.

Liquid Nails though I don't use ever. Because, I found it in multiple situations & renovations where it was barely 10-years old & up to 30-years old & the entire range was always dried out & completely released from everything, worthless.

Solvent-Free adhesives would really just be used for low VOC situations or upholstery, fabric, foam & foam-board applications, where you don't want to damage what's being glued.

Comment: To be fair, the formula for Liquid Nails is probably very different than it was 10 or 30 years ago.